# multiple if statements and logical operators

Tags: r

I'm trying on a simple task, but my code is behaving strangely and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Now I simply want to convert my continuous matrix vector to a factor vector with three levels. Code is below.

Now the issue is that the output does not correspond correctly to what it should be. E.g how can the third output become `"> 1500"`, what can be wrong?

Code

```
funcion.x <- function(x) { if (x < 500)  x  <- "<500"
              if(x > 500 & x < 1500) x <- "500-1500"
              if (x > 1500)  x <- "> 1500"

              return (x)
}

> x
      [,1]
 [1,]   28
 [2,]  341
 [3,]  758
 [4,]  665
 [5,]  583
 [6,]  695
 [7,]  424
 [8,]  302
 [9,]  197
[10,]  181
[11,]   86
[12,]   68
[13,]   34
[14,]   24
[15,]   18
[16,]    8
[17,]    6
[18,]    5
[19,]    3
[20,]    3
[21,]    1
[22,] 4438

> apply(x, 1, function.x)
 [1] "<500"   "<500"   "> 1500" "> 1500" "> 1500" "> 1500" "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"  
[17] "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "<500"   "> 1500"
```

Comment: try using `else if` or using another name for your `x`, it looks like you are overiding x and then testing it again, so in your third output, x will be ""500-1500" after the second if and `"500-1500" > 1500` is `TRUE` so it returns `>1500`

Comment: In general, you should use braces to tidy up your if statements. Also think what will happen if you pass in 500 or 1500 to your function

Comment: isn't `ifelse(x < 500, '< 500', ifelse(x < 1500, '500 - 1500', '>= 1500'))` enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this function:

```
function.x <- function(x)
{
  c("<500","500-1500",">1500")[which.max(x<c(500,1500,Inf) | x==c(-Inf,1500,Inf))]
}
```

akrun's proposal to use "cut" *almost* works. The problem is that "cut" produces half open intervals. But here we want one closed interval and two open intervals. To deal with this I included the strange "x==c(-Inf,1500,Inf)" into my function.